# how to send rich push to APNS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I can send a regular push just fine but cannot figure out to send a "rich" push. I've read Apples "Local and Push Notification Programming Guide" 5 times and it makes no mention of sending anything other than an alert, badge and sound. I cannot find any documentation for rich push in the developer center.

I must be looking for the wrong thing, maybe someone else has been down this road already?

Comment: what do you mean by "Rich Push" ?

Comment: Sending HTML5 as the body of the message. I can't find anything about it online but everyone where I work seems to think it's possible to send a video or image via push. And they call this technique a "rich push".

Comment: They are joking with you. Push Notifications are just short messages. They are not such things as rich push. Just look at your notification center. If it's not a joke they may talk about the message shown after the application did launch. You can associate an url with the push and then when you open it you can show any HTML5 message you want, but within the app.

Comment: Thank you Francescu! This makes perfect sense, now I understand. So what I should be doing is passing a custom parameter to specify the url the app should display when tapping the push message.

How can I flag your comment as the solution?

Comment: I copy/paste bellow as an answer so you can accept it ;) Good luck with APNS and your app !

Comment: I agree with Francescu, Push Notifications are just short messages and you can't send images directly in the payload. But you can cheat a bit and send the URL to an image or HTML file in the payload, and then have your app look at the URL in the notification payload, fetch the data from this URL and display it in your app. Maybe that's what they call "rich push"? See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't send a whole HTML content directly in your notification, but you can send "rich push" in the sense that you can send additional data in your Push Notifications, and not just `alert`, `badge` and `sound`: **you can send any other key you want/need**. (just put them outside of the `aps` entry of your JSON, like at the root of the JSON object).

Only limitation is that you are limited to 255 characters, so that's **not** designed to provide sthg like a large HTML file for example. Just to provide some additional keys of your choice, like for example an URL, some fields to describe internal ids of objects you want to display, etc.

Everything is described [here in the Local and Push Notifications Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1): look at the paragraph called "Examples of JSON Payloads", where they add dummy parameters like `"acme1"` and `"acme2"`.

So applied to your case your could have a payload like that for your Push notification:

```
{
    "aps" : { "alert" : "Message received from Bob" },
    "rich-text-url" : "http://yourserver/message/1234"
    "id-of-object-to-show" : 456
}
```

The only thing to keep in mind is the 255 characters limit.
*(Note: obviously the descriptive keys in my example above are only for explanation but one generally choose shorter key names like `url` and `id` instead to shorten the overall payload)*

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/